# Why am I not able to create an NGINX server for my FASTAPI

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to setup NGINX to run FASTAPI.

I am trying to run FastAPI using nginx on AWS EC2 instance. I first ran the following command to create a nginx proxy_server:

```
 sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fastapi_nginx
```

After that I wrote the following code in the file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 3.X.X.X(PublicIP);


        location / {
                    proxy_pass http:/127.0.0.1:8000;
                   }
        }
```

To check if everthing is working properly, I ran the following command:
`

```
 sudo service nginx restart
```

However, I recieved the following error:

```
systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
nginx[4846]: nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fastapi_nginx:7 nginx[4846]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

`

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http:/ -> http://

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `http:/` or add another `/` in the proxy_pass before local host